# Can't reach metadata in viewmodel in my view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to use metadata in my view but my model(ToDoTable) is packed in viewmodel(ModelsViewList) and I don't know how to reach the model.The @foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties) doesn't work :(.

Model:

```
public partial class ToDoTable
        {
            [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
            public int ID { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please write name of event.")]
            public string EventName { get; set; }



            [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Description must be shorter than 50 characters ")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę podać opis.")]
            public string Description { get; set; }


            [Display(Name = "Tu wpisz format daty")]
            [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date mast be in format described")]
            public string Data { get; set; }
        }
```

Controller:

```
 using System.Web.Mvc;
        using ToDoLibrary.Abstract;
        using ToDoUI.ModelsViews;

        namespace ToDoUI.Controllers
        {
            public class HomeController : Controller
            {
                IToDoRepository repository;
               public HomeController(IToDoRepository rep)
               {
                    repository = rep;
               }
                public ViewResult List()
                {
                    ToDoLibrary.ToDoTable model = new ToDoLibrary.ToDoTable();
                    ModelsViewList modelView = new ModelsViewList()
                    {
                        FromRepository = repository.FromRepository,
                        ModelDB = model
                    };
                   return View(modelView);
                }

           }`
       }
```

View:

```
@model ToDoUI.ModelsViews.ModelsViewList
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "List";
    }
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 main tile1 col-lg-push-6">
            pierwsza kolumna

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                <div class="panel-body">

                    @foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
                    {
                        switch (property.PropertyName)
                        {
                            case "ID":


                                break;
                            default:
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>@(property.DisplayName ?? property.PropertyName)</label>
                                    @if (property.PropertyName == "Description")
                                {
                                        @Html.TextArea(property.PropertyName, null, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 5 })
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    }
                                    @Html.ValidationMessage(property.PropertyName)
                                </div>
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Zapisz" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    @Html.ActionLink("Anuluj i wróć do listy", "Index", null, new
               {
                   @class = "btn btn-default"
               })
                </div>
            }
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property name should be more like `ModelDB.ID` as your metadata is related to `ToDoUI.ModelsViews.ModelsViewList` which contains a property `ModelDB`, which is your `ToDoTable` object you are referencing.

Otherwise :

```
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders.
     Current.GetMetadataForType(null, Model.ModelDB.GetType());
```

This will give you the metadata of your TodoTable you can then go through your properties. Anyway I am not sure it will help you to do something decent... As it doesn't look like it will :)

Comment: Yes I know but how to do this  without changing @model ToDoUI.ModelsViews.ModelsViewList

Comment: I'm not sure indeed that the metadata of your child objects are loaded in the model. So the best way is to pass your TodoTable object in a new view, where you will definitely have access to your metadata. But you can try case "ModelDB.ID" before doing this :-)

Comment: I am working on project where unfortunately everything must be in  one view.

Comment: It is not allowed to make more views than one :(. This is for job recruitment process project.

Comment: Coming message "cannot convert from 'ToDoLibrary.ToDoTable' to 'System.Func<object> '

Answer (score 1):

You can't. However, the problem is not one of how to get the metadata from the entity class, but rather instead, that the entity class should not have this metadata in the first place. These annotations belong on your view model. The entity class should only have things that matter to the database, not your view.

Comment: Ok, but is there some way how to provide model(ToDoTable) with metadata and viewmodel (@model ToDoUI.ModelsViews.ModelsViewList) to the same view?

Comment: No. Again, put the view logic on your view model.